# StoredQueries in WFS 2.0.0 in WFS 2.0.0 plugin for QGIS

Tags: web-services, geolocation, maps, qgis

I'm testing storedQueries on our INSPIRE web services for theme CadastralParcels. When I run it in browser, everything is OK, but when I tried to get features via QGIS (in version 1.8.0 Lisboa) using WFS 2.0.0 plugin by Jürgen Weichand, I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/medm/.qgis//python/plugins\wfsclient\wfsclientdialog.py", line 727, in httpRequestFinished
root = ElementTree.parse(str(self.outFile.fileName())).getroot()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1177, in parse
tree.parse(source, parser)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 654, in parse
self._root = parser.close()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1636, in close
self._raiseerror(v)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1488, in _raiseerror
raise err
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Version of Python:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, f440b60

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 
'C:/Users/medm/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/medm/.qgis//python/plugins', 
'C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\bin\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

Here is a query I've used in browser:
[http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-cp-wfs.asp?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedQuery_id=GetParcel&srsName=EPSG::5514&KATUZE_KOD=601527&TEXT_DEF_BOD=1](http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-cp-wfs.asp?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedQuery_id=GetParcel&srsName=EPSG%3a:5514&KATUZE_KOD=%3CLiteral%20xmlns=%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%20xmlns%3axs=%22http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema%22%20type=%22xs%3astring%22%3E601527%3C/Literal%3E&TEXT_DEF_BOD=%3CLiteral%20xmlns=%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%20xmlns%3axs=%22http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema%22%20type=%22xs%3astring%22%3E1%3C/Literal%3E)

please notice that parametres are braced in `<Literal>` tags, so the real address of link is `http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-cp-wfs.asp?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedQuery_id=GetParcel&srsName=EPSG::5514&KATUZE_KOD=<Literal xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="xs:string">601527</Literal>&TEXT_DEF_BOD=<Literal xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="xs:string">1</Literal>`

In the same way, parameters are filled in QGIS WFS 2.0.0 plugin:
I wanted to place a screenshot her, but I don't have enough reputation.
Query parametres are exactly the same in browser and in WFS 2.0.0 plugin. Then, when I click getFeatures, I get mentioned error.
Can anybody help me? Or does anybody have similar problem?

Thanks
Michal

Answer (score 0):

I tested your example:

- QGIS 1.8 and WFS 2.0 Client 0.8.4 on Windows → failed
- QGIS 1.8 and WFS 2.0 Client 0.8.4 on Linux → works fine

I will do some more investigation on this (URL-Encoding e.g.).

Why did you use fes:Literal instead of xs:String (or xs:int) for the parameters?

GetFeature-Example using fes:Literal

```
http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-cp-wfs.asp?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&STOREDQUERY_ID=GetParcel&KATUZE_KOD=<Literal xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="xs:string">601527</Literal>&TEXT_DEF_BOD=<Literal xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="xs:string">1</Literal>
```

Possible GetFeature-Example using xs:String

```
http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-cp-wfs.asp?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&STOREDQUERY_ID=GetParcel&KATUZE_KOD=601527&TEXT_DEF_BOD=1
```

Comment: Thats strange, in my case it failed both in Linux and Windows with same error. What distribution are you using? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: xs:String is probably better solution, I didn't like that long Literal construction, but thats not main problem. But its good note and I share your opinion

Comment: SUSE 12.1 - QGIS 1.8.0-8.10 with GDAL 1.10-5.6 // OT: GDAL 1.10 detects the correct geometry (the parcel itself, not the reference point)

Comment: I'm using GDAL 1.9.2. That could be the problem. I'm gonna actualize and test again.